# With python static typing/mpy, can I say "this method has the same/similar type signature as method X"?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to override an initializer method but not copy all the static typing from the base method:

```py
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, *, message: str, error_code: int):
        self.message = message
        self.error_code = error_code

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *, details: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.details = details
```

I'd really like to not have to copy the signature of `BaseClass.__init__` into `SubClass.__init__` in order to get static checking of the parameters. Is it possible to indicate to static typing/mypy that `SubClass.__init__(**kwargs)` are the parameters/types declared in `BaseClass.__init__` ?

I was not able to find a syntax or "delegating typing" model that would allow this after having read through both the [python typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) documentation as well as the [mypy cheat-sheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html)

Ideally, I'd like code like the following to raise a mypy error/warning:

```py
SubClass(message="foo", error_code=13, details="badness", stack_trace=[1, 2, 3])
```

SubClass does not accept an argument with the name "stack_trace".

Comment: You don't want to copy them anyway, because the point of using `kwargs` is to capture arguments that you *don't* know about at compile time. The use case for `super` is simply "too" dynamic for static typechecking to fully apply.

Comment: @chepner signature copying for this exact usecase is an accepted feature request: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270

no, that's absolutely not the sole point of kwargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: [no, there is an open feature request](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/270).

In your particular case, you can use dataclasses to tell mypy about the kwargs:

```
MYPY = False

if MYPY:
    from dataclasses import dataclass

    @dataclass
    class BaseClass:
        message: str
        error_code: int

    @dataclass
    class SubClass(BaseClass):
        details: str
else:
    class BaseClass:
        def __init__(self, *, message: str, error_code: int):
            self.message = message
            self.error_code = error_code

    class SubClass(BaseClass):
        def __init__(self, *, details: str, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.details = details
```

The code above typechecks with latest mypy and detects wrong usage of your class, and still runs on Python versions without dataclasses. You can put the dataclass definition into a `.pyi` file to enable support for Python 2.

You can also get rid of your `__init__` code and use dataclasses all the way if you can drop older Python versions.